# Insert Arrow depending on If Statement in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I am trying to insert an Arrow based on whether one cell number is bigger than another. The data I have is as follows.

```
     C         E

6  20800     20400
7  5038       6003
8  46325     46325
```

The if statement I have currently is as follows as I wish to add to this.

```
For lngI = 1 To 3
If Worksheets("Front End").Cells(lngI + 5, 3).Value > Worksheets("Front End").Cells(lngI + 5, 5).Value Then
    Worksheets("Front End").Cells(lngI + 5, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
ElseIf Worksheets("Front End").Cells(lngI + 5, 3).Value < Worksheets("Front End").Cells(lngI + 5, 5).Value Then
    Worksheets("Front End").Cells(lngI + 5, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
ElseIf Worksheets("Front End").Cells(lngI + 5, 3) = Worksheets("Front End").Cells(lngI + 5, 5) Then
    Worksheets("Front End").Cells(lngI + 5, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
End If
Next lngI
```

So currently all I am doing is highlighting based on whether Cell values in Column C are larger, smaller or equal to corresponding Cell values in column E.
Therefore I would like to insert a green arrow pointing upward next to the number in Cell (C,6), a red downward arrow next to the number in Cell (C,7) and a yellow sideway arrow next to the number in Cell (C,8).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's a upward arrow? You mean something like `->` and `<-`? Or just greater/smaller sign: `>` or `<`?

Comment: Can "*next to*" be in a helper column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without any VBA if you're ok with the arrow appearing in an adjacent cell rather than in the cell itself.

The formula  `=IF(C1>D1,"é",IF(C1<D1,"ê","è"))` will give you the correct arrows with the font set to **Wingdings**.
You can then use conditional formatting to set the colour.

**Edit after answer accepted:**
This will add the arrow to the end of the number in the cell.
The contents of the cell will be treated as text after the update - performing any mathematical function (such as `SUM`) on the cells will return a #VALUE error.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lngI As Long
    Dim CharToAdd As String
    Dim ColourToUse As Long

    For lngI = 1 To 3

        With Worksheets("Front End")
            If .Cells(lngI, 3) > .Cells(lngI, 4) Then
                CharToAdd = " é"        'Up arrow.
                ColourToUse = -11489280 'Green.
            ElseIf .Cells(lngI, 3) < .Cells(lngI, 4) Then
                CharToAdd = " ê"        'Down arrow.
                ColourToUse = -16776961 'Red.
            Else
                CharToAdd = " è"        'Right arrow.
                ColourToUse = -16711681 'Yellow.
            End If

            'Add the character to the end of the number.
            'Note - cell is now a text string.
            .Cells(lngI, 3) = .Cells(lngI, 3) & CharToAdd

            'Format last character in cell.
            With .Cells(lngI, 3).Characters(Start:=Len(.Cells(lngI, 3)), Length:=1).Font
                .Name = "Wingdings"
                .Color = ColourToUse
            End With
        End With

    Next lngI

End Sub
```

If you want the arrows to appear at the start of the cell:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lngI As Long
    Dim CharToAdd As String
    Dim ColourToUse As Long

    For lngI = 1 To 3

        With Worksheets("Front End")
            If .Cells(lngI, 3) > .Cells(lngI, 4) Then
                CharToAdd = "é "        'Up arrow.
                ColourToUse = -11489280 'Green.
            ElseIf .Cells(lngI, 3) < .Cells(lngI, 4) Then
                CharToAdd = "ê "        'Down arrow.
                ColourToUse = -16776961 'Red.
            Else
                CharToAdd = "è "        'Right arrow.
                ColourToUse = -16711681 'Yellow.
            End If

            'Add the character to the start of the number.
            'Note - cell is now a text string.
            .Cells(lngI, 3) = CharToAdd & .Cells(lngI, 3)

            'Format first character in cell.
            With .Cells(lngI, 3).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font
                .Name = "Wingdings"
                .Color = ColourToUse
            End With
        End With

    Next lngI

End Sub
```

I'll look into the conditional formatting rules.....

Comment: This is a good solution to the problem, but I think OP was looking for conditional formatting Icons (Arrows).

Comment: @EliasWick Good point.  I've never had need to use them before.  I'll have to look into that - not sure how the second icon works (_when <= Formula and >_).  In the mean time I'll add a VBA solution to.

Comment: Thank you! This isn't a academic project so I thought it would be easier for it to be done in VBA but this solves my problem. However if there is a way for this to be done in VBA it would be really useful to know, for future reference :)

Comment: Perfect VBA answer! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

same method, you can try the following characters as well

```
Sub Up_arrow()
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "á"
With ActiveCell.Font
    .Name = "Wingdings"
    .ColorIndex = 10
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub

Sub Down_arrow()
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "â"
With ActiveCell.Font
    .Name = "Wingdings"
    .ColorIndex = 46
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub


Sub Right_arrow()
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "à"
With ActiveCell.Font
        .Name = "Wingdings"
        .ColorIndex = 40 ' or 22
        .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```